# Virtualbox Mouse Lag

Tags: windows-xp, virtualbox, virtual-machine, mouse

My mom has a laptop and i installed VirtualBox on it because i missed it so much,I created a VM with Windows XP SP3 and installed some games on it,The problem is that when i leave my mouse alone,Everything runs fine but when i move it the vídeo and sound starts to lag a bit.

Now i have a Windows 10 desktop with VirtualBox with the same Windows XP installation and i have many games on it,When i move the cursor on that VM it works just fine.

Can somebody help me?Is that a difference between installing VirtualBox on a laptop and on a desktop?

Comment: basically... speed. Without more detail, that's all anyone can say, but laptops are not known for being fast. Twice the price for half the speed would be a fair guess.

Comment: Install VirtualBox guest additions. Enable 3d video acceleration. Increase video memory and system memory. Disable any background app which does not require.

Answer (score 0):

In one word, **RAM**. 
The RAM assigned to the VM on the laptop must be **less** than the RAM assigned to the VM on the Desktop.

Comment: Would it even allow you to set more? My VM software wouldn't.

Comment: I made a VM with 512 MB of RAM,Let's see if this works.

Comment: It didn't work,And that's strange because when the laptop had Windows 8 the VM worked fine.